# I want to create an OnClick event for cardview element i.e TextView to go to different activities through it. How can I create it?

Tags: onclicklistener, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am not getting how to go to different activities after clicking on the specific TextView which is inside the cardview. Below are the files of my project. ThankYou

```
ChemicalAdapter.java

    package com.example.tejask.chemilife_project;

import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by tejas k on 29-09-2015.
 */
public class ChemicalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChemicalAdapter.ViewHolder>  {

    List<NatureItem>mItems;

    public ChemicalAdapter() {
        super();
        mItems = new ArrayList<>();
        NatureItem nature = new NatureItem();
        nature.setName("RO Chemicals");
        nature.setDes("Accepta's range of high performance reverse osmosis chemicals " +
                "They are based on advanced formulations and include RO membrane cleaners and detergents," +
                " scale inhibitors and antiscalants, corrosion inhibitors, biocides, antifoulants, de-chlorinators and flocculants.");
        mItems.add(nature);

        nature= new NatureItem();
        nature.setName("Boiler Chemicals");
        nature.setDes("This range of chemicals are “all in one boiler treatments” which incorporate a boiler water oxygen scavenger, alkalinity builder, polymer sludge conditioner and, where appropriate, a phosphate treatment. " +
                "They are matched to the feed water quality to ensure that the correct boiler water chemistry is achieved.");
        mItems.add(nature);

        nature=  new NatureItem();
        nature.setDes(" Cooling Tower water chemical programs are effectively used for the reduction and prevention of the three major issues " +
                "      your industrial cooling water system may encounter: corrosion, deposition, and microbial growth.");
        nature.setName("Cooling Tower Chemicals");
        mItems.add(nature);

        nature= new NatureItem();
        nature.setName("Sugar Processing Chemicals");
        nature.setDes("The Sugar cane processing chemicals are widely used in Sugar mills. They are used for processing," +
                "Sugarcane in a handy way.Our company provides various types of Sugar Processing Chemicals at an affordable price");
        mItems.add(nature);

        nature= new NatureItem();
        nature.setName("Effuleant Treatment Chemicals");
        nature.setDes("We provide various types of Effuleant Treatment Chemicals");
        mItems.add(nature);

    }
      @Override
      public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int i){
          View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_card_view, parent, false);
          ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
          return viewHolder;
      }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ChemicalAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int    position) {
        NatureItem nature = mItems.get(position);
        viewHolder.tvNature.setText(nature.getName());
        viewHolder.tvDesNature.setText(nature.getDes());
      //  viewHolder.tvDesNature.setOnClickListener(this);
       // viewHolder.imgThumbnail.setImageResource(nature.getThumbnail());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

      class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

          //  public  ImageView imgThumbnail;
            public TextView tvNature;
            public TextView tvDesNature;

            public ViewHolder(View itemView){
                super(itemView);
                tvNature = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_nature);
                tvDesNature=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_des_nature);      


            }
      }

    }

This below class is for declaring getters and setters
    NatureItem.java
    package com.example.tejask.chemilife_project;

/**
 * Created by tejas k on 29-09-2015.
 */
    public class NatureItem {

    private String Name;
    private String Des;


    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getDes() {
        return Des;
    }

    public void setDes(String des) {
        Des = des;
    }
    }
The below class is Activity where the CardViews are shown along with  RecyclerView.
CardActivity.java
package com.example.tejask.chemilife_project;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
```

/**
 * Created by tejas k on 29-09-2015.
 */
    public class CardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cardview);
    recyclerView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    layoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    mAdapter = new ChemicalAdapter();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

}

In below file I have declared the Recyclerview.

cardview.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    /></LinearLayout>

In the below file. I have declared the cardview along with Textview. It   serves as an UI for the activity.

recycler_card_view.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#db7093"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click Them To Know Details"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20dp"/>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
    android:id="@+id/cardview"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    card_view:cardElevation="0.01dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/top_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#db7093">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_nature"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="#006666"
    android:alpha="0.8"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    android:text="Test"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_nature"
        android:id="@+id/tv_des_nature"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:onClick="true"
        android:textColor="#006666"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
  </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, onClick attribute should specify the name of the method which is invoked. So, instead of

`android:onClick="true"`

in your layout definition, it should be something like

```
android:onClick="onClickHandler"
```

Then in your Activity subclass you define it like so:

```
public void onClickHandler(View v) {
    // obtain myValue
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("my_key", myValue);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: In which file, should I have to define layout definition, from above two xml files? And Why do I need Put Extra in here? And I also want to go to several activities as there are around 5 cardviews present.i.e 5 activites. Thank You